# Поля "name" в форме для универсальной обработки

Tags: php, запрос, form

Вывожу в таблицу данные которые нужно обработать:

```
<?foreach ($basket as $item) {
$i++;
?>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="name[<?=$i?>]" id="name" value="<?=(!empty($item->name )) ? $item->name : ''?>">
</td>
<td><input type="text" name="surname[<?=$i?>]" id="surname" value="<?=(!empty($item->surname )) ? $item->surname : ''?>"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="age[<?=$i?>]" id="age" value="<?=(!empty($item-
>age )) ? $item->age : '
'?>"></td>
<?}?>
```

Если в `name` я записываю `[<?=$i?>]` то в `$_POST` приходит массив только не такой какой мне нужен (name => array, surmame => array). Так не удобно записывать данные в БД. Как правильно отправить форму чтобы пришел массив таблицы, а не каждого элемента массив отдельно?

Comment: а какие данные у вас в $basket ? какая структура ?

Comment: Массив в массиве [0] Array .., я думаю это не имеет значение.

Comment: конечно имеет значение, если у вас будет  массив name=>'Вася', surname=> 'Пупкин' то вы сможете красиво подставить $key при foreach а не вставлять $i

Comment: да именно такой массив..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?foreach ($basket as $k => $item) {?>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="products[<?=$k?>][name]" id="name" value="<?=(!empty($item->name )) ? $item->name : ''?>">
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="products[<?=$k?>][surname]" id="surname" value="<?=(!empty($item->surname )) ? $item->surname : ''?>"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="products[<?=$k?>][age]" id="age" value="<?=(!empty($item-
    >age )) ? $item->age : '
    '?>"></td>
    <?}?>
```

В итоге вы получите $_POST[products], который будет выглядеть так:

```
[0] => [name => "value",
        surname => "value",
        age => "value"] 
[1] => [name => "value",
        surname => "value",
        age => "value"] 
     ...
```

Comment: Ваш ответ мне помог, вместе с тем парень выше (Arsen) написал про key это вместе $i подставить key?

Comment: Он имел ввиду следующую конструкцию, чтобы код был более элегантным: foreach ($basket as $k => $item) - в таком случае можно выкидывать $i++ и все $i заменить на $k. $k - это ключ массива. $_POST['products'] - в данном случае $k = 'products', если $basket[0] то $k = 0

Answer (score 0):

**`name="key[value]"`** для инпута создаёт массив значений по ключу **`key`** c множеством **`value`**. Делайте так:

```
<input type="text" name="name<?=$i;?>"... и далее по аналогии
```

С **`$_POST`** в таком случае придут **`name1=value, name2=value, etc.`**